# How can I quantify uncertainty for a least squares estimator in a multivariate linear regression with covariance structure?

Tags: least-squares, multivariate-normal-distribution, uncertainty, multivariate-regression

Suppose that we have
$$\mathbf{y}\sim\text{N}(\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta},\sigma^2\mathbf{M}\mathbf{M}'),$$ and let $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$ be the least squares estimator for $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. How can we quantify uncertainty for $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$? At first, I thought that $\text{Var}(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})=\sigma^2\mathbf{M}\mathbf{M}'(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}$, but this does not result in the correct dimensions. For example, if we let $\mathbf{y}$ be $n\times1$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ be $p\times1$, then this doesn't work out.

Comment: If you're familiar with Generalized Least Squares, then a mere change in notation will express your model in that form and you can apply its formulas.  But a quick search of this site indicates nobody has yet derived or posted the GLS formulas for the standard errors in GLS.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. I think that opened up a rather easy line of work to get the variance. I posted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

A general result from least squares estimation is that
$$\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}=(X'X)^{-1}X'\mathbf{y},$$ where we can treat $\mathbf{C}=(X'X)^{-1}X'$ as constant. Then, we can apply the variance over $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$ to get
$$\text{Var}(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})=\sigma^2\mathbf{C}\mathbf{MM}'\mathbf{C}.$$